# Splitting a cell containing a list of text values into other cells, depending on the values in the list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm wondering whether it's possible to split a cell that contains a comma-separated list into various columns, based on a reference table that is editable, using **only** Google Sheets formulae and not resorting to Apps Script.

I have created a simplified version to better explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I am presented with a table like this:

[image: Simplified starting table]

In `A2` there is a list of colour names, and I would like them to be sorted into the correct columns in new, smaller lists. The ideal solution would look like this:

[image: Simplified ideal solution]

Ideally I would do this with formulae that live in `B2`, `C2`, and `D2`. What goes in which cell though has to be dynamic, so that if new options came about they could be sorted into the correct cells.

I imagine the best way to achieve this whilst keeping what goes in which column dynamic would be to have the formulae compare against a a reference table living in a "master" document. For example:

[image: Simplified reference table]

The formula in `B2` would reference table column `A`, `C2` would reference table column `B`, etc.

This way the formulae would not require editing - which I want to avoid as this system would be used across many different Google Sheets documents.

Whilst this is certainly achievable using Apps Script, I would rather the formulae do the heavy lifting so that if someone inherits my role further down the line they aren't required to understand Apps Script/JS etc. to maintain and/or modify the system.

I would imagine that the process involves `SPLIT` and `JOIN` by `", "`, and possibly a `LOOKUP` (or `VLOOKUP`), but I can't work out how (or even if) it's possible.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste under REDS and drag to the right:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(REGEXMATCH($A11:$A, "(?i)"&
 TRANSPOSE(FILTER(master!A2:A8, master!A2:A8<>""))), 
 TRANSPOSE(FILTER(master!A2:A8, master!A2:A8<>""))&",", )),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(""&ROW(A11:A), SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(A11:A)&"♠♣"&IFERROR(TRIM(
 SPLIT(LOWER($A11:$A), ","))&"♦")), "♣"), 
 "select max(Col2) 
  where Col2 matches '^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, IF(B2:B8="",,LOWER(B2:B8)&"♦"))&"$' 
  group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "♠")), "♦$", ), "♦", ","), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: what would I need to add to the `REGEXMATCH` so that it only matched exact words from the reference table? So if "Royal Blue" was in the colours list, it wouldn't match with both "Blue" and "Royal Blue"

Comment: Thanks again @player0 !